# ISP is inserting ads into web pages

Tags: browser, isp, adblock, advertisements

My ISP is inserting ads into web pages randomly (it is like a popup in the bottom right side). I have tried different browsers but same thing happens. I know it is not caused by any virus because ads are for the ISP's apps and other things. With another ISP in a different area there are no ads. I can't change my ISP, and complaining is a waste (I have already tried).

Someone told me I can hide ads with an ad blocker, but I want to block the ads completely so no data are wasted for downloading them.  Is this possible?

Comment: If you are using chrome use this plugin to block ads [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=en).
For Firefox  use this plugin [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/).
These plugins blocks almost almost all ads from well known domains that publishes ads but since in your case the ads are injected from your ISP you might need to configure the plugins to block the source from which your ISP is pushing in the ads.

Comment: Ayan my friend has said use ad block and i have written in the question, but i want to kill download itself. what i think is ad block is downloading but hiding ads isn't it? also ads are different so how i can even ad block all? i have to do one by one for all? there should be better solution!!

Comment: Ad blockers usually strips off the request to the ad service or tracking scripts. You can find more about it in this [article](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2487367/e-commerce/ad-blockers--a-solution-or-a-problem-.html). Now there is no harm in trying and see what happens with a adblocker but it looks like you are stuck with the misconception you have about it. I have been using adblockers for years and advised many people who are annoyed by ads to use them.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/1087669/blocking-the-isps-ads-appearing-after-a-possible-dns-grab-and-redirect-via-port

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to beat this:

1. Only go to the https: version of the website. There are browser add-ons that help you do this (e.g. [HTTPS EveryWhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)). This won't help you if the sites only have a http: version.
2. Use a [Virtual Private Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network). There are many VPN providers available, probably some free ones as well.
3. Install an Ad blocker (like [AdBlock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/)). Chances are that the IP adresses that the adverts come from are already in the block list of the add-on. If they are not, you have to trace the domain names or IP ranges that they come from (they may very well come from *one* ad provider), and manually add that information to the block list. Data from those web addresses will not be retrieved.

Methods 1 and 2 ensure that your traffic is encrypted when it passes through the ISPs' computers. They cannot see (and change) the HTML/Javascript that way.<sup>*</sup>

Although you say *I can't change my ISP*, that *would* be the preferred solution. Leave and tell them you left for that reason. Losing customers is the only argument they will listen to, and this will help other customers too.

If you are absolutely sure that you ISP is doing this, I invite you to edit your question and name them.

<sup>* This assumes that your provider has not asked you to install their certificate so that [they can decrypt your traffic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48170/how-a-provider-can-tap-an-internet-line-even-for-ssl-encrypted-connection). This is unlikely, I have not heard from providers that do so. If they do, method 1 is not going to work. A VPN still will.</sup>

Comment: #3 --> How exactly trace them?

Answer (score 0):

Add Blockers do actually typically reduce the bandwidth by not downloading the ads, so the suggestion is good.

A web works by downloading the main html page, then all the resources directed in that page - particularly images etc.   An ad blocker will prevent the downloading of these images from occuring, thus the bandwidth is never used.

You have not advised where you are or your financial means or tenacity, but other then an ad blocker you are not going to be able to solve this problem without other compromises.  I realise these may not be options for you, but you could explore a few options -

1. Setting up a VPN or proxy service to bypass the ISP's interception 
   of your packets.
2. Take legal action against your ISP (don't know your jurisdiction, but
   there are a number of avenues, including "interference with business
   relations" and specific versions thereof -  Of-course they probably have
   deeper pockets then you, and its probably not worth your time.
3. Set up your last mile backhaul (eg using WIFI) to another provider.

Comment: "An ad blocker will prevent the downloading of these images from occuring, thus the bandwidth is never used." This is important since the OP has a misconception that ad blocking still results in bandwidth usage. Since the ISP injects code into the HTML delivered to the browser, if the browser (thanks to the ad blocker) simply ignores the ad-related code then the resource requests will never be made. The only extra bandwidth used in that case would be for whatever the ISP injected into the HTML itself, which shouldn't be all that much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more of a moral nature than technical.
File a spam complain to the ISP.
If in your contract it is not specified that they use these ads (while offering an ads free service), they have no right to spam you.

Comment: OP says complaint has been filed and ignored.