# Blocking the ISP's ads appearing after a possible DNS grab and redirect via port 53?

Tags: networking, dns, browser, javascript, advertisements

I'm asking this question here because I already asked it on ProWebmasters and the moderators said the people on SuperUser might be able to answer it.

**The question:** https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93552/blocking-the-isps-ads-appearing-after-a-possible-dns-grab-and-redirect-via-port

Being a programmer, I'm quite embarrassed that I'm unable to block the ads, and would appreciate some help.

ps: I considered linking to the question instead of re-posting everything here, but if you feel it is more appropriate for me to post the contents of the question here, please let me know. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Which DNS server answers you? Have you tried to set up your own recursive DNS server somewhere outside, set it up as your DNS at home and then check if your local queries really reach your server from your IP? Also, what is interesting - how HTTPS looks? No ads? Every https site is untrusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not some DNS spoof. The ISP is actively altering web requests and injecting their own adware. If you look carefully at your snippet, the variable which stores a GET request has as part of that request a command to pipe part of a google javascript file through it's own code.

A quick look on the web for similar complaints points to the ISP picking some random (the first listed? all?) script tag on the returned page, and rewriting it to point to their own adware script which then pipes the original script through their servers. If I had to guess, I would say they are also probably doing this for their own profit as well (google ad revenue etc, not just by feeding you ads, but possibly rewriting any google analytics calls from the originating script to make it look like their content etc etc).

You should drop them, this is shady and they lie about it. You might also want to drop a line to google. They may or may not be are messing with their analytics but what they are doing is against google policy for ad partners.

I would be curious to see what an https request looks like...

Comment: If ISP is not transparent they're very, very wrong. It means we should vote with feet - do not pay them and do not use their services. But I seriously doubt Google policies should have any importance for any ISPs. Is Google an Internet King Who Everybody Should Respect or so? Why should I respect their rules when I don't use their service?

Comment: Like you said: revenue. If they are manipulating google ad revenue streams, google may pull the plug. They will have a better chance than the OP to get satisfaction.

Comment: That is Google problem, and not mine or my ISP. I consider Google ads not better than anybody else: they're just piece of crap in my eyes.

Comment: I said to "make a compliant to google." Not "threaten the ISP." Whether google can, will, or ought do something about it is out of our hands and not even relevant. What the ISP is doing is potentially stealing from google. Even criminal organizations do not like to be robbed.

Comment: The ISP is run by the government, and is the least costly. Other ISP's are no better in terms of service either, and are more costly. My question though, was about being able to block the ads. Seems like others are facing similar issues: http://bitsnapper.com/how-to-block-intrusive-mtnl-broadband-ad-popups-in-your-browser/

Comment: @nav: it is important to understand that 1) this is a "man-in-the-middle type of attack (regardless of who is doing it)  only worse because it is administrator sanctioned (the isp) and; 2) if you block the script, you block the functionality of the website, since their script functions as a proxy